# Including the cell borders in a vba script for dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba

My code is supposed to copy the dynamic set of data from Sheet1 and Sheet2 to Sheet3 and 4 respectively.
After the copying and formatting is done, I need to apply borders to the dynamic range.

This is how my script looks like

```
Sub transfer()
Dim Lastrow As Integer
Dim Lastrow1 As Integer
Dim row1 As Long
Dim row2 As Long
Dim range1 As Range
Dim range2 As Range



Lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
Lastrow1 = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
Debug.Print Lastrow
Debug.Print Lastrow1


Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:G" & Lastrow).copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2")
Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B2:H" & Lastrow1).copy Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("B2")

With Worksheets("Sheet2")
 row1 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
 Debug.Print row1
 Set range1 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1:G" & row1)
 With range1.Borders
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0

    End With
End With

With Worksheets("Sheet4")
row2 = Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
Debug.Print row2
Set range2 = Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("B1:H" & row2)
With range2.Borders
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0

    End With
End With

End Sub
```

But The borders are not happening only when I am in the specific sheet even though I specified the sheetname.
Also, the borders drawn are inconsistent and not being applied to the entire range for sheet4

Would appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Comment: `Range("B1:H" & row2)` is referring to the active sheet...

Comment: @braX I have edited the code, but the borders are filling up ambiguously.
If I run the script, sheet 4 is filling up with fine but borders of sheet 2 are getting filled with the range of sheet4

Comment: Step through the code and verify that each time you get one of your lastrow variables you are getting what you expect.

Comment: I have check the values of the variables and both of them have a different value(32 and 37) but the borders are getting drawn for both the sheets with the configuration of SHEET4 @braX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably trying to do something like this (all instances of the sheet need to be qualified)

```
With Worksheets("Sheet4")
  row2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
  Set range2 = .Range("B1:H" & row2)
  With range2.Borders
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
  End With
End With
```